# Would this jQuery is.(":hidden") work?

Tags: jquery

I'm playing around with the 'is' filter in jQuery and I am currently without the opportunity to use a testing server.

What I want to know is...would this work to display both hello and goodbye?

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    if ($("p").is(':visible')) {
        $(this).css('display','block');
    }

});

<p>hello</p>
<p style="display:none">goodbye</p>
```

Basically what I want to do is run an action on something when it is visible but not run it when it isn't.

Thanks guys

Comment: Just a hint, you can test this stuff using jsfiddle.net :-)

Comment: Try to run it. If it doesn't work, then it doesn't work.

Answer (score 2):

> Basically what I want to do is run an
>   action on something when it is visible
>   but not run it when it isn't.

I think you mean that you're trying to execute something on one or more visible elements? Then you would just need to use the visible filter *within* your selector:

```
$("p:visible").doSomething();
```

Comment: Thanks very much. I actually need it in an if statement, which is why I was using the is.

I have it working now. YAY!

Answer (score 0):

Here is your answer --> http://jsfiddle.net/5FrGn/1/

No it doesn't, it only displays `Hello`

Answer (score 0):

For these types of try outs use [jsfiddle.net](http://jsfiddle.net/). It is an awesome site which would enable to work with multiple JS libraries at one go.

HTH

Comment: Thanks very much for the heads up. It looks like a great site

Answer (score 0):

What your code is saying, basically, is that whenever any visible paragraph is clicked, it's made visible. I'm pretty sure that's not what you're trying to achieve...

However, yes, the concept is right - if you try `$(element).is(":visible")` it returns `true` if the element is visible, and `false` otherwise.